# Unfortunately [yourapp], has stopped

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using intent method to make a simple app that takes you from main screen [with an enter button] to another screen which has three options. Code sourced online and seems to be error free, though my app crashes saying "Unfortunately [yourapp], has stopped" immediately after i press the button which is meant to take to the the other screen.

This is my first activity code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enterBtn);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   

        }

    });

}
```

}`

And this is my landing screen's activity code:

```
import android.app.Activity;    
import android.os.Bundle;    
import android.widget.Button;    

public class HomeActivity extends Activity {    

Button button;    

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
}
```

}

I'm really stuck with this issue and any help would be much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: post your `logcat` and you may defined `other activity` in your `AndroidMenifest`

Comment: Have you registered your HomeActivity in your AndroidManifest ?

Comment: Try following the steps here : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: i haven't registered my HomeActivity in my AndroidMsnifest, how do i do that. I'm sorry i'm a newbie in android!

Comment: you can use this one  <activity
        android:name="packagename.HomeActivity"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every activity needs to be added in your manifest file under application tag. This seems to be the problem in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to post you `LogCat` so that we might get some more information and if you have not yet added your `Activity` in the `manifest`, this is the way of adding it (Activities go under application tag)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.southmp3"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

all the Activities should be going under the application tag

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to register my new activity on the androidmanifest.xml file. That's what sorted my app crash issue.